# Maintaining the state of a div across jquery refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

**The story**

[Live demo](https://kund.glasgarden.com/taxibeta/?date=2013-02-16)

I use jQuery auto_refresh function, which reloads a specific div containing the bookings and refreshing information from the database every 5 sec. counting down remaining time ond so on..

Bookings are displayed in a list-view which simplified looks like this:

```
pickup: 15:00 from: thisway 53 to: thatway 23 who: Mr. Andersson note: credit card
pickup: 15:30 from: wayout 33 to: wayoverthere 12 who: Mrs. Morgan note: wheel chair
```

**The problem:**

```
<script> 
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){ $(".refresh").load('?date=<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>&id=' +Math.random()+ ' .refresh').fadeIn("fast");
}, 5000); // refresh every 5 sec 
</script>

<div class="refresh"> [booking content] 
<a href="#info-113">Show detailed info</a>
<a href="#cancel-113">Cancel booking</a>
<div class="info" id="113">Detailed information. information code. This is hidden until requested.</div>
</div>
<div class="cancel" id="113">Cancel booking. cancel code. This is hidden until requested.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

It seems **impossible** to prevent the toggle.div from vanishing every time the jquery.div reloads. If a div is requested visible it needs to remain so even after the auto refresh. (because it also handels updates/cancels/assigns) but it seems jQuery while reloading the div content also removes the hashtag in some weird way.

I would be very grateful if anyone could help my out here, im ooooh, so stuck!!

Comment: Are you saying you need to maintain the state of the div across refreshes?

Comment: Yes i do, but the collapse when jquery reloads the div in which they are contained. Divs outise of the reloading div, howevere, doesnt.

Comment: im terrible at explaining. I hop you guys get my question. How do i get jquery to understand that a divs state should remain across refreshes.

Comment: Can you share the code where you call auto-refresh??

Comment: <script>
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function(){
$(".refresh").load('?date=<?php echo $_GET['date']; ?>&id=' +Math.random()+ ' .refresh').fadeIn("fast");
}, 5000); // refresh every 5 sec
</script>

Comment: https://kund.glasgarden.com/taxibeta/

Comment: Update your question with the code.

Comment: Ive updated my question. Also, theres a link to a live example above. Which shows the problem with my divs..

Comment: if you replace all the html will need to store `state` somewhere first. You haven't provided any detail about what `state` means in your case. Also might consider only updating data and not replacing it

Comment: Hm. but if i request #info-113 to show, it puts the state in the adress bar, right? As long as the div is outside of the refreshing div theres no problem. Im not sure what more detailes i can provide. See the live demo for to see the problem in action. (click on one of the icons to the right - and watch them collapse on refresh.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in another way. Keeping your page in a iframe inside a div and refreshing it using PHP easily.

Comment: Ok, could you provide me with an example?